# When writing a Vertica transform function, is there a way to get an identifier for the partition

Tags: vertica

I am attempting to write a user-defined transform function in Vertica.  Each execution of processPartition() within my UDTF implementation ends up generating an output file on disk.  I would like some way to uniquely identify those files based upon the number of partitions into which Vertica has divided my operation (i.e. 1-4, 2-4, 3-4, 4-4).  But it does not appear that I have access to any sort of identifier beyond the name of the executing node (from ServerInterface).

Does there exist some value that I can use to uniquely identify the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more insight what you plan to do in processPartition() ? Maybe there are other ways to get to the same result!